# Logging exceptions with spring web flow

Tags: spring, logging, spring-webflow

Hy,

I am a newbie with Spring Web Flow. I am trying to find out what the easiest way to log exceptions is within a flow file. There is a tag called `exception-handler` but I cannot find any documentation about how to log exceptions. I know the exceptions of third party libraries are get logged(`spring`, `hibernate`) but I want to handle the exception and create my own log entries.

Answer (score 0):

**Controller Based Exception Handling**

Using `@ExceptionHandler`

```
@Controller
public class ExceptionHandlingController {

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView getExceptionPage(Exception e, HttpServletRequest request) {

        // Catches all exception
        // Do anything with Exception object here

        if (isAjax(request)) {
                // If exception comes for Ajax requests

            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("forward:/app/webExceptionHandler/ajaxErrorRedirectPage");
            model.addObject("exception", exception);
            model.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());
            model.setViewName("error");
            return model;

        } else {
            // If exception comes for all non Ajax requests
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("forward:/app/webExceptionHandler/nonAjaxErrorRedirectPage");
            model.addObject("exception", exception);
            model.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());
            model.setViewName("error");
            return model;

        }

    }

     @ExceptionHandler({SQLException.class,DataAccessException.class})
        public String databaseError() {
            // Catches specific exception SQLException
        return "databaseError";
  }

     private static boolean isAjax(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return "XMLHttpRequest".equals(request.getHeader("X-Requested-With"));
    }

}
```

**Global Exception Handling**

Using `@ControllerAdvice` Classes

A controller advice allows you to use exactly the same exception handling techniques but apply them across the whole application, not just to an individual controller. You can think of them as an annotation driven interceptor.

Any class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` becomes a controller-advice and three types of method are supported:

```
@ControllerAdvice
class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
    public void handleConflict() {
        // Nothing to do
    }
}
```

Please [refer](http://ankursinghal86.blogspot.in/2014/07/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc.html) for more details.

Comment: Ok, but how is then configured this Controller in the flow file? Do I have to declare it as a exception handler?

Comment: @user3254515 Please [refer](http://ankursinghal86.blogspot.in/2014/07/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc.html) for more details.